# Error in installing Scrapy in Ubuntu Fresh Install

Tags: python, ubuntu, scrapy

I am trying to install `scrapy` module in Ubuntu (running in Virtualbox on a Windows Machine).

When I do `pip install scrapy`, I get the following error at the end of the install:

```
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenise;
__file__='/tmp/pip-build-csKz7u/Twisted/setup.py';
exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" 
install --record /tmp/pip-FIY6qO-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-csKz7u/Twisted
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

What am I missing or doing wrong here?

Comment: Anything illuminating in `/root/.pip/pip.log`?

Comment: not sure. Here it is: http://pastebin.com/FVUrNuRW

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu doesn't come with the python header and library by default it's in `python-dev`. Run the following to install before installing scrapy.

```
sudo apt-get  update; sudo apt-get install  python-dev -y
```